# Confusion about lifetime and borrows in a nested for loop in a method

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a stack of cards. So I have structs for cards and suits. But when I try to initialize all combinations of cards to make the cardstack it has a problem with borrows and lifetimes.
I can't for the life of me understand how to solve this issue. And yes, I already read the chapters on lifetimes etc.

The errors start at the line at the end, where the parameters for Card::new does not have the right lifetime. But I don't know how to put correc lifetime on these:

```
stackvector.push(Card::new(cardsuit, number))
```

```
use rand::thread_rng;
use strum::IntoEnumIterator;
use strum_macros::EnumIter;

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, EnumIter)]
pub enum CardSuits {
    Hearts,
    Spades,
    Diamonds,
    Clubs,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Card<'a> {
    pub suit: &'a CardSuits,
    pub number: &'a u32,
}

impl<'a> Card<'a>  {
    pub fn new(new_suit: &'a CardSuits, new_number: &'a u32) -> Self {
        Card { suit: new_suit, number: new_number }
    }
}

pub struct CardStack<'a> {
    pub stack: &'a Vec<Card<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> CardStack<'a> {
    pub fn new(cardsuits: CardSuitsIter, stackvector: &'a mut Vec<Card>) -> Self {
        
        for cardsuit in cardsuits {
            for number in (1..=13).into_iter() {
                stackvector.push(Card::new(cardsuit, number))
            }
        }
        Self { stack: stackvector }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using references in `Card` at all, it'd be simpler and likely more efficient with fields as simple `CardSuits` and `u32`.

Comment: When you borrow something, something else has to own it. So conceptually, if you are borrowing the `number` then who owns it? It looks like you're manufacturing numbers in the for loop that only live for that iteration. Where are those numbers kept afterwards?

Comment: Add `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` to `CardSuits`. Then you can get rid of the lifetimes. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d27b746456f20135113ded48d7f7517c)

Comment: Consider that a pointer is actually like a number. When you pass objects *by reference*, you actually copy a pointer to that object, which means copying a number. If you pass them *by value*, you copy your obejct. So, if your object is a simple `enum` with four variants and no additional information on either variants, you'll understand that there is no point in passing it *by reference*: in either way, you copy the same amount of memory; but in the former, you need to handle an memory ownership model, and add a reference layer.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to implement your problem with references.

Look at the following part of your code:

```rust
for number in (1..=13).into_iter() {
    stackvector.push(Card::new(cardsuit, number))
}
```

With `Card::new` expecting a `number: &'a u32`.

No matter what the lifetime `'a` is, the `number` will stop existing after the end of the `for` loop, as it is a variable local to the `for` loop. Therefore, storing a reference to it outside of the `for` loop is an error in every programming language, many other programming languages just simply don't complain.

**The solution:** Just use `copy`s instead. Both `number` and `cardsuit` are primitive types. `number` being a `u32` and `cardsuit` being an `Enum` that doesn't carry a nested value.

Therefore, make `CardSuits` `Copy` and remove the references:

```rust
use strum_macros::EnumIter;

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, EnumIter, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum CardSuits {
    Hearts,
    Spades,
    Diamonds,
    Clubs,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Card {
    pub suit: CardSuits,
    pub number: u32,
}

impl Card {
    pub fn new(new_suit: CardSuits, new_number: u32) -> Self {
        Card {
            suit: new_suit,
            number: new_number,
        }
    }
}

pub struct CardStack<'a> {
    pub stack: &'a Vec<Card>,
}

impl<'a> CardStack<'a> {
    pub fn new(cardsuits: CardSuitsIter, stackvector: &'a mut Vec<Card>) -> Self {
        for cardsuit in cardsuits {
            for number in (1..=13).into_iter() {
                stackvector.push(Card::new(cardsuit, number))
            }
        }
        Self { stack: stackvector }
    }
}
```